# Updating ListView show old data even after updatting with new data in ArrayAdaptor

Tags: android, listview

For couple of days i am struggling to update ListView data in ArrayAdaptor with new data list but its not working.
    I have searched many topics about this on stack overflow but my problem is still there.
    I have already tried the listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); method but nothing happening.
    I am posting my code here, please help me with it.  Thanks

Here is MyTabActivity.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MyTabActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager Tab;
    TabPagerAdapter TabAdapter;
    ActionBar actionBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_layout);
        TabAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        Tab = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Tab.setOnPageChangeListener(
                new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar = getActionBar();
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);                    }
                });
        Tab.setAdapter(TabAdapter);
        actionBar = getActionBar();

        //Enable Tabs on Action Bar
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
//              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tab ReSelected: " + tab.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                Tab.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
//              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tab Selected: " + tab.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
//              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tab UnSelected: " + tab.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }};
            //Add New Tab
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1").setTabListener(tabListener));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2").setTabListener(tabListener));

    }
}
```

Here is TabPagerAdapter.java

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public TabPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new Tab1Activity();
        case 1:
            return new Tab2Activity();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        //No of Tabs
        return 2; 
    }
}
```

Here is Tab1Activity.java

```
public class Tab1Activity extends Fragment {
    ViewPager tabPager;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, container, false);
        tabPager = (ViewPager) container.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        List<String> dataList = prepareData();
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_View1);
        ListRowAdaptor listAdapter = new ListRowAdaptor(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.list_row, dataList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArrayList("newData", (ArrayList<java.lang.String>) prepareNewData());

                Tab2Activity myDetailFragment = new Tab2Activity();
                myDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.pager, myDetailFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                tabPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            }});
        return view;
    }

    public List<String> prepareData(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item1");
        list.add("Item2");
        list.add("Item3");
        list.add("Item4");
        list.add("Item5");
        list.add("Item6");

        return list;
    }

    public List<String> prepareNewData(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("New Item1");
        list.add("New Item2");
        list.add("New Item3");
        list.add("New Item4");
        list.add("New Item5");
        list.add("New Item6");

        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is Tab2Activity.java

```
public class Tab2Activity extends Fragment {
    ListRowAdaptor listAdapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_View1);
        List<String> dataList = prepareData();
        listAdapter = new ListRowAdaptor(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.list_row, dataList);

        if(bundle != null){
            List<String> newList = bundle.getStringArrayList("newData");

            listAdapter.clear();
            listAdapter.addAll(newList);
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        return view;
    }

    public List<String> prepareData(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item11");
        list.add("Item22");
        list.add("Item33");
        list.add("Item44");
        list.add("Item55");
        list.add("Item66");

        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is activity_main2.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_View1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is tab_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"`enter code here`
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</RelativeLayout>*
```

Comment: Did you try notifyDataSetInvalidated()?

Comment: Yes I tried, but still the view is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is that you set the adapter

```
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

after you notify the data set changed

```
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You can try to write these sentece just before the "notify" sentence.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, container, false);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_View1);
        List<String> dataList = prepareData();
        listAdapter = new ListRowAdaptor(inflater.getContext(), R.layout.list_row, dataList);

        if(bundle != null){
            List<String> newList = bundle.getStringArrayList("newData");

            listAdapter.clear();
            listAdapter.addAll(newList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);   // Update the adapter before notify
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Let me know if it works. Good luck.

Comment: Even after setting the adaptor as u said before the notifyDataSetChanged() method, the view still is not changed.

Comment: Well, it is possible, when you inflate the same xml file from two different Fragments the "inflator" create two different instances of the same structure? If it is possible you're working in two different Fragments with two different ListView instances, in that case you're updating the wrong ListView.

Comment: i am new to android, I am not sure how to check if there are two instance created of inflator. The code I have given above is working, it would be a great help if you could try to run this code at your and see whats going wrong. I literally tried all solution which are told here, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to below

```
 if(bundle != null)
 {
      List<String> newList = bundle.getStringArrayList("newData");
      dataList.clear();
      dataList.addAll(newList);
      listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Comment: I changed the code as above, but still the view is not changed.

Comment: did you getting new data or prepared data in listview

Comment: I am still getting the prepared data not the new data which I wanted to load

Comment: write  listView.setAdapter(listAdapter); before checking bundle

Comment: I have tried writing listView.setAdapter(listAdapter); before checking bundle, but still no effect, listview still not chnaged

Answer (score 0):

The `notifyDataSetChanged()` method notify the observers of your adapter.

If you're using a gridview for example, you can call `invalidateViews()` method, this will cause the view to be rebuilt and redrawn.

Comment: I am using ListView, still I tried what you said but its not working

Comment: You can call 'invalidateViews()' on a listView. Try to check if your bundle is null, if it isn't put `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);`